# Custom tool bar menu item xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I would like to achieve similar tool bar menu item. I would like to add image in left and text in right. Image is font awesome icon. So I would like to create custom template with label . And show like this menu item . I have tried absolute layout with listview . It not working. I am thinking to use picker but it occupy full screen.but it needs to display like in image .. any one please help on this to overcome issue.[image]

Comment: Popup page might worth trying for.

Comment: I want to achieve it without third party or nuget.. popup page is xamarin default one . Thanks

Comment: @dinesh,Maybe you need to use Page render to find toolbar, then find Menuitem, you can create custom view to replace the view in Menuitem, I think this is a bit complicated, because you need to bind command for new custom view.